# i want to access child node data using parent node name flutter firebase data base

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-realtime-database

```
{
  
  "centers": {
    "DCSE": {
      "centerName": "DC"
    },
    "SE": {
      "centerName": "ccc"
    },
  }
}
```

`stdRef =FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child('centers').child('centerName');`
i  would like to access centerName without knowing its nodes names DCSE and SE as its possible to do? i want to access centerName with parent name `cneter` instead of ***centers.DCSE.centerName***

child('centers').child('centerName') directly????

Comment: Doesn't seems any possible solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't know which center to show the name of, all you can do is show the name of all centers. That'd be something like:

```
final centersRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref("centers");

centersRef.onValue.listen((event) {
  for (final centerSnapshot in event.snapshot.children) {
    print('${centerSnapshot.child("centerName").value}');
  }
}, onError: (error) {
  // Error.
});
```

Also see the Firebase documentation on [listening for value events](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/flutter/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events).